# Are functions pointers a safe alternative to tightly coupled classes?

Tags: c++, c++14

Let’s say MyClass needs info from the Util class. Is the following example of function pointer use safe? Note that this is running on an embedded system where CPU resources are tight.

Correct me if I’m wrong but I believe this has a number of advantages:

1. Unit testable
2. Removes coupling between classes
3. Runtime performance is better than if Util::TheTruth() was run separately and the result passed to myObject as a parameter.

However, literature does not provide me much guidance on this.

```
class Util {
public:

  static bool TheTruth() {
    return a || (!b && c);
  }

  bool a = false;
  bool b = false;
  bool c = false;
  
};

class MyClass {
public:

  MyClass() {
    IsItTrue = &MyClass::ReturnFalse;
  }
  MyClass(bool (*_IsItTrue)(void)) {
    IsItTrue = _IsItTrue;
  }
  void Handler() {
    if (serviceRequest) {
      truth = IsItTrue();
    }
  }

private:

  bool (*IsItTrue)(void);
  static bool ReturnFalse() { return false; }

  bool truth;
};

int main() {

  Util utility;
  MyClass myObject(&Util::TheTruth);
  
  while (true) {
    if (condition) {
      myObject.Handler();
    }
    
    // Some other code
  }
}
```

I have tried something similar to this and get the expected behaviour; IsItTrue() gets the same result as TheTruth() but in fewer cycles.

What are the risks of using this method?

Comment: There’s no way it’s faster than calling `TheTruth` directly.  It might be faster than some _other_ form of dependency injection.

Comment: That's basically a "Command" pattern, implemented as a function pointer, but could as well be implemented with a function object / functor

Comment: How is this not tightly coupled? It uses the literal class name in the constructor of `MyClass`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_IsItTrue`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: The main risk with this method is the same risk as with any use of pointers - the potential to pass an invalid pointer.   Since you can't control the code that *uses* your class, you can't prevent such things (e.g. accidental or deliberate passing a bad pointer).   Incidentally, your implementation of `Util::theTruth()` will not compile, since it has a static member accessing non-static members without any reference to an instance that contains those non-static members.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I can understand the risk of an unassigned pointer. The phrasing of the question should have been more around portability Vs CPU overhead. Directly calling Util::TheTruth() inside a MyClass method would create an undesirable dependency between classes. Therefore, I want the freedom to bind a function at instantiation with a small overhead cost: one degree of redirection.